# Getting an error about unclosed opening bracket for a function in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have this code:

```
<?php
function good_day() { ?>
    'Good Day';
<? }

good_day();
?>
```

It gives me an error about unclosed `{` which I expect. However, It is inspired from the code ina a blog post that I was reading. It looks like this:

```
function social_media_links() { ?>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>
      .....
    </ol>
<?php }
add_filter( 'footer_links', 'social_media_links' );
```

Is this code valid or invalid in the context of WordPress? Is there any file in WordPress where I could put the above code and it would be considered valid?

Lets say the code is valid and it will work in WordPress, isn't using `echo` still a better approach for doing this?

Comment: _"It gives me an error about unclosed `{`"_ - only because you did not "start" the PHP parser again correctly. `<? }` wants to be `<?php }`

Comment: Thanks @CBroe :) Is doing it this way just personal preference or is it considered good or bad practice?

Comment: This is a good way of doing things, if you had to output a larger chunk of HTML code, with only small parts of it being dynamic. Then you would only go `<?php echo $someValue; ?>` directly inside the place where the dynamic content needs to go, and keep everything else around it "outside of" PHP. You can spare yourself a lot of trouble with double quotes / single quotes & escaping, especially if the HTML code would contain both types of quotes in nested form to begin with.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe :) You have been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare it like this:

```php
<?php
function good_day() { 
    echo 'Good Day';
}
?>
```

And use it like this:

```php
<?php good_day() ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Sparkle but 'php tag it will be processed as regular text so it will be printed anyway. ' did not happen when I removed the call the `good_day()`. The text `Good Day` was only output with the function call in my version of code.

Comment: Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right, my mistake.